# iterate through a sorted query in parse?

Tags: parse-platform

I am writing a cloud function that has a query:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("A");
query.ascending("age");
```

After the find comes back I iterate through the results:

```
query.find({
    success: function(results){
        // here I iterate through and want to iterate through expecting to follow the sort...
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
            a = results[i];
            console.log(("found A object after save, age = "+ a.get("age"));
        }
    },
    error:function(......
    ........
})
```

The problem is that the log **does not print the "a" object ordered by age.**

How can I iterate through the A objets here in order, so following the age sorting the query should give me back?

Comment: what is the type of the age field?

Comment: is it printing the objects in the wrong order or is it not printing anything?

Comment: it is a Number. Printing in wrong order...

Comment: Would you show us what it prints?